# React Native - java.lang.RuntimeException after publishing the app in Google play store

Tags: android, react-native

This is a stack trace from Google play developer console after publishing my new react native app.

I'm not really sure where to begin investigating this? Does anyone have any ideas?

I got that error from different devices and different android versions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3555)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3707)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2220)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8019)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:566)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:57)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:390)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:74)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:2454)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:196)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:287)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:115)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate (ReactActivity.java:45)
  at com.marwan.mosaed.dietforever.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7957)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7946)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3530)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:343)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.<init> (ScreenFragment.kt:42)
```

[image]